# Custom view cover on the status bar which navigationBar is hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, statusbar

The rootViewController of window is a navigationController (The iOS SDK is 7.0.).

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
MyNavigationController *nav = [[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

Now I set the navigationBar hidden in MyNavigationController:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
    {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;
        self.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = NO;
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
    }
}
return self;
```

}

And then add a btn on ViewController:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.navigationBarHidden = YES;

        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
        {
            self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
            self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;
            self.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = NO;
            self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

But the btn was on the status bar. How could I solve it?

Comment: Your MyNavigationController's initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil will not be called as you are initialising it with different initialiser, initWithRootViewController and hence the code in initWithNibName will not be taken into effect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried to put the code in ViewDidLoad, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post screenshot of the screen to get a glimpse of the defect you are talking about?

Comment: [screenshot.png](https://www.dropbox.com/s/utbk475e7dm48zs/iOS7Test.png)